# How can pythoncom.PumpMessages() restart after PostQuitMessage?

Tags: python, hook, pythoncom

I use a hook to check for Mouse Event and Keyboard Event, and I create a new thread for the hook because I have some other work to do.

The hook thread consumes CPU all the time, so I want to pause it occasionally (for efficiency). I tried using PostQuitMessage() to stop it and then wait to restart the thread and PumpMessages() at the right time. but it doesn't work.

I am looking forward to receiving your answers!

The following is the main part of the code,you can run it then will get the problem.
ps. Excuse my broken English~_~

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
#Python version:3.5.4
from win32 import win32process
import time
import threading
#import win32
import psutil
import PyHook3 as pyHook
import pythoncom
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    print('-----Mouse-----', event)
    return True
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print('-----key-----', event)
    if str(event.Key)=='F12':   
        win32api.PostQuitMessage()
    return True

def InputScan():
    print('-----InputScan-----')
    hm.MouseLeftDown = OnMouseEvent
    hm.HookMouse()
    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    hm.HookKeyboard()
    #first time is worked normally,but re-execution not working
    pythoncom.PumpMessages() 
    return True


print('start program...')
threads = []
nowThreadsName=[]
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
try:
    ThreadIS = threading.Thread(target=InputScan, name='ThreadIS', args=())
    ThreadIS.setDaemon(True)
    threads.append(ThreadIS)
    ThreadIS.start()
except:
    print("Error:--")
while 1:
    #some other works
    time.sleep(5)
    open_str = input("whether restart(anykey): \n")
    nowthread = threading.enumerate()
    nowThreadsName.clear()
    print("nowThreadsNameclear=",nowThreadsName)
    for i in nowthread:
        nowThreadsName.append(i.getName())
    print("nowThreadsName=",nowThreadsName)
    if 'ThreadIS' in nowThreadsName:
        pass
    else:
        t = threading.Thread(target=InputScan, name='ThreadIS', args=())
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start() #why it dosen't work??
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: I have found the key to solve this problem.

Comment: PumpMessages() must be write in the main thread and it only consumes CPU a little in fact.